# Flutter-Conditional formatting based on unique characters within a string. Is it possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and have an application that uses a realtime database composed of long text strings. I am unable to separate the string itself into different sections and am wondering if it would be possible to apply conditional formatting with RichText(). I have seen that package of easy_rich_text and wanted to do something similar, but don't see an option to modify the string after the target text has been identified.

For example, if I had a string with "Apples are /red/ fruit", I could have flutter detect the string within the // and have font color red, while the remainder is black. Is this possible? And if so, How should I go about writing code for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using the package [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) is probably the easiest way:

```dart
Widget widget = Html(data: 'Apples are <span style="color: #ff0000">red</span> fruits');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I explained it well above. I want the code to detect the "/" symbol for example and conditionally format that text within it's boundaries. With a single function, I could have the code also work for "Paintbrush with /red paint/ and blue water", without having to specify any specific parameters other than the target character "/".

Comment: In this case I think the other answer from Brett Sutton is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Try this. It sounds like it should do the trick.
To be clear you  need to parse the string yourself and thei render the results into the widget.